# How to create/read nested dictionary from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, logic

Here is the text file1 content

```
name = test1,description=None,releaseDate="2020-02-27"
name = test2,description=None,releaseDate="2020-02-28"
name = test3,description=None,releaseDate="2020-02-29"
```

I want a **nested dictionary** like this. **How to create this?**

```
{ 'test1': {'description':'None','releaseDate':'2020-02-27'},
  'test2': {'description':'None','releaseDate':'2020-02-28'},
  'test3': {'description':'None','releaseDate':'2020-02-29'}}
```

After this I want to append these values in the following line of code through "for" loop for a list of projects.

Example: For a `project="IJTP2"` want to go through each name in the dictionary like below

```
project.create(name="test1", project="IJTP2", description=None, releaseDate="2020-02-27")
project.create(name="test2", project="IJTP2", description=None, releaseDate="2020-02-28")
project.create(name="test3", project="IJTP2", description=None, releaseDate="2020-02-29")
```

Now to the next project:

List of projects is stored in another file as below

```
IJTP1
IJTP2
IJTP3
IJTP4
```

I just started working on Python and have never worked on the nested dictionaries.

Comment: This doesn't look like any file format I've seen. What if the name or description contains `=`, `,`, or `"`?

Comment: I will be creating these text files. And they will not have any special characters @AlexHall

Comment: Then don't create those text files like that. Use a standard format such as JSON (then you could store your nested dictionary directly) or CSV.

Comment: yes that would be way easier. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that:

- each file line has comma-separated columns
- each column has only one `=` and key on its left, value on its right
- only first column is special(name)

Of course, as @Alex Hall mentioned, I recommend JSON or CSV, too.

Anyway, I wrote code for your case.

```
d = {}
with open('test-200229.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        (_, name), *rest = (
            tuple(value.strip() for value in column.split('='))
            for column in line.split(',')
        )
        d[name] = dict(rest)

print(d)
```

output:

```
{'test1': {'description': 'None', 'releaseDate': '"2020-02-27"'}, 'test2': {'description': 'None', 'releaseDate': '"2020-02-28"'}, 'test3': {'description': 'None', 'releaseDate': '"2020-02-29"'}}
```